# Unable to include .key file in typescript build

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, typescript-typings, tsconfig

I have a `public.key` and `private.key` file in my folder structure that is not being included in the build ie, when I run `tsc`.

I am using the public/private key pairs to generate a json web token.
This is how i am importing the file which works fine and generates the token.

```
private publicKey = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "../../utils/keys/public.key"), "utf8");
```

Same code applies for the private.key just with the filename change.

This is my `tsconfig.json` file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist/",
    "pretty": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "paths": {
      "*": ["node_modules/*", "src/*", "*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Is there a way I ask typescript to include the `*.key` file?

Comment: The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . How do you use the file and why is it expected to be included?

Comment: @estus updated the question to reflect the same

Comment: This may be not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36690779/typescript-copy-files because of XY problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript transpiles `*.ts*` and `*.js*` files. This isn't a task for TypeScript to process non-script files and include them into a build.

Bundling is a task for Webpack, which can be used to load arbitrary files with respective loaders, e.g. `file-loader`, but files are expected to be used with `import` or `require` in this case and not `fs`. Also isn't necessary to use Webpack with Node.js applications because they don't benefit from this that much as client-side applications.

In this case `keys` shouldn't be a part of `dist` at all, unless proven otherwise. It can reside outside of `src` or `dist` and be on the same level of nesting:

```
dist
  ...
src
  ...
util
  keys
```

Since relative paths are expected to be same within both `src` and `dist`, there should be no problems linking to `util/keys`

Comment: that sounds great but the problem arises when I'm trying to deploy on heroku, I need to run a `git push to heroku` which will do an `npm install`l and then run `tsc` to transpile the files to `js` and runs the server, Now in order for the server to generate token It would need the keys, how do I handle something like that on heroku? Environment variables?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. Just commit key files to the repo. You have other files besides `src`/`dist` that are needed for the app to run, like `package.json`. Key files are among these files.

Comment: Yep just tried it, works perfectly, thank you so much. Is there a better way of deploying private keys to heroku ie, should they be converted to a string and used as an env variable?

Comment: Giad it worked. This depends on how private these private keys are. I don't use Heroku myself but yes, environment variable is a good place to store things you don't want to commit, especially if a key is a string. In this case you may want to read a key from `process.env` first before trying `fs.readFileSync`